# Access the id of the closest matched tag

Tags: jquery

I have a `select`. I need to access the canvas `id` when I change my select. I have this code now.

I seems to get an empty object from my code (as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duzuK.png)), 
but I want to get the string `bw`.

```js
$("select[name='last']").on('change', function() {
  var selectedVal = $(this).val();
  console.log($(this).closest('canvas'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<small class="lastSelectedMenu">
  <span> 
    Current Interval:
    <span class="lastSelected"></span>
  </span>
  <select name="last" class="float-right">
      <option id="default" value="default">Select Interval</option>
      <option value="day">Day</option>
      <option value="week">Week</option>
      <option value="month">Month</option>
      <option value="year">Year</option>
  </select>
</small>
<canvas id="bw"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest()` only looks at parent elements. As the canvas is a sibling of a parent element then you need to use a combination of  `closest()`, to get the nearest parent element which is a sibling of the canvas, `.lastSelectedMenu` in this case, and then `next()`.

This will given you a jQuery object containing a reference to the `canvas` element. To get the `id` string from that you can use `prop()`. Try this:

```js
$("select[name='last']").on('change', function() {
  var selectedVal = $(this).val();
  var $canvas = $(this).closest('.lastSelectedMenu').next('canvas');

  console.log($canvas.prop('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<small class="lastSelectedMenu">
    <span>
      Current Interval:
      <span class="lastSelected"></span>
    </span>
    <select name="last" class="float-right">
        <option id="default" value="default">Select Interval</option>
        <option value="day">Day</option>
        <option value="week">Week</option>
        <option value="month">Month</option>
        <option value="year">Year</option>
    </select>
</small>

<canvas id="bw"></canvas>
```